# cannot connect to php file located on webserver through ajax?

Tags: javascript

Based on some research i went through i believe that XmlHttpRequest doesn't permit cross-domain data-exchange directly.Thus my below code does not connect to the getstopname.php file stored on the webserver(1freehosting.com).

How do i convert my below Java script code so that it can access the php file stored on a remote web server directly ?

```
  function getDirection(str)
              {  
              if (str=="")
                {
                document.getElementById("select-choice-direction").innerHTML="";
                return;
                } 

              if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
              else
                {
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
              xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                  {

                   $('#select-choice-stopname').html(xmlhttp.responseText).selectmenu( "refresh");
                   $('#select-choice-stopname-postuser').html(xmlhttp.responseText).selectmenu( "refresh");
                 }
                }
              xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.xyz.com/getstopname.php?direction="+str.value+"&bus="+busnum+"&dayofweek="+dayofweek,true);
              xmlhttp.send();
              }
```

getstopname.php file (stored on a diffrent web webserver)

```
<?php

$bus = intval($_GET['bus']);
$q = $_GET['direction'];
$dayofweek = $_GET['dayofweek'];

$con=mysqli_connect("xyz.com","root","root123","db1","3306");

ct_db($con,"db1");

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT StopNames FROM cfv_busstopnames WHERE UniqueBusId = '".$q."' and busnumber = ".$bus."  and Dayofweek = '".$dayofweek."' ");

  echo "<option>" . "Pick Stop  Names? ". "</option>" ;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {

  echo "<option>" . $row['StopNames'] . "</option>" ;

  }

?>
```

Comment: [Same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) applies in this situation. You need to have the file on the same host, so that you can use relative URIs. However, you may always proxy the file through your server, such as `get_file.php?xyz.com...`.

Comment: it works fine if i host both the file on the same webserver. I even tried on wamp and it works fine the problem is when i try to access ajax code from my localhost to the php file which is hosted online on a different webserver.

Comment: Well, since you own both hosts, you can always setup [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using JQuery for the selectors, so why not use JQuery's ajax method

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

There is an option for crossDomain.

Answer (score 0):

You can try allowing CORS:

At the very top of `getstopname.php`:

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); //remember to replace the * with the domain the JavaScript is running from

$bus = intval($_GET['bus']);
$q = $_GET['direction'];
$dayofweek = $_GET['dayofweek'];

//rest of the code
```